# Four boxplots on one figure with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

So I have multiple data files, all of which I am using dataframes in order to easily process the information. All of the files are NetCDF files. I am trying to plot 4 boxplot graphs on the same figure, so that they all are easily able to be compared (I am looking at how averages across the same time selections peak at different times). They will have differing X and Y values as this is observational data that was taken at slightly different time intervals and the different variable numbers correspond to different time-dependent variables.

I have been trying to use subplots to make this happen using matplotlib, but it just spits out three empty graphs. How can I make this happen?

Here's the code:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
ds1 = xr.open_dataset(lfile1)
one_day1 = ds1[variable1].sel(time=slice(monthofi+startday+' '+starttime,monthofi+endday+' '+endtime))
df1 = one_day1.to_pandas().to_frame(name=variable1)
df1.index=df1.index-pd.DateOffset(hours=7)
df1.boxplot(column=variable1, by=df1.index.time, whis=[10, 90], sym='')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Temperature [degF]')
plt.title('Daily Cycle')
plt.suptitle('')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
ds2 = xr.open_dataset(lfile2)
one_day2 = ds2[variable2].sel(time=slice(monthofi+startday+' '+starttime,monthofi+endday+' '+endtime))
df2 = one_day2.to_pandas().to_frame(name=variable2)
df2.index=df2.index-pd.DateOffset(hours=7)
df2.boxplot(column=variable2, by=df2.index.time, whis=[10, 90], sym='')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Average Wind Speed')
plt.title('Daily Cycle')
plt.suptitle('')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
ds3 = xr.open_dataset(lfile3)
one_day3 = ds3[variable3].sel(time=slice(monthofi+startday+' '+starttime,monthofi+endday+' '+endtime))
df3 = one_day3.to_pandas().to_frame(name=variable3)
df3.index=df1.index-pd.DateOffset(hours=7)
df3.boxplot(column=variable3, by=df3.index.time, whis=[10, 90], sym='')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Wind  Direction')
plt.title('Daily Cycle')
plt.suptitle('')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
ds4 = xr.open_dataset(lfile4)
one_day4 = ds4[variable4].sel(time=slice(monthofi+startday+' '+starttime,monthofi+endday+' '+endtime))
df4 = one_day4.to_pandas().to_frame(name=variable4)
df4.index=df4.index-pd.DateOffset(hours=7)
df4.boxplot(column=variable4, by=df4.index.time, whis=[10, 90], sym='')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Solar Radiation [W/m^2]')
plt.title('Daily Cycle')
plt.suptitle('')

plt.show()
```

What exactly is not happening?

Alright, Now, I edited it so that it follows like such:

```
plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
df1.boxplot(column=variable1, by=df1.index.time, whis=[10, 90], sym='')
ax1.set_title('Daily Cycle')

ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
df2.boxplot(column=variable2, by=df2.index.time, whis=[10, 90], sym='')
ax2.set_title('Daily Cycle')

ax3 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
df3.boxplot(column=variable3, by=df3.index.time, whis=[10, 90], sym='')
ax3.set_title('Daily Cycle')

ax4 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
df4.boxplot(column=variable4, by=df4.index.time, whis=[10, 90], sym='')
ax4.set_title('Daily Cycle')

plt.show()
```

Now, I am getting five windows with five figures. One figure that takes up the entire window has all of the data that should be in the four subplots, while the other four figures have a subplot each in them in the positions I would like, but empty.

Comment: I don't see you call `plt.boxplot()` with the data. I think that is why they are blank.

Comment: now, I'm using df.boxplot(...). Does this not plot for plt.subplot?

Comment: well, I think since you created the figure and the suplot with `plt` that you need to actually plot it using `plt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only getting three graphs because you are giving [subplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot) the wrong arguments and overwriting axes you previously created. 
From the documentation:

```
subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number)
```

nrows is the number of rows of subplots in figure and and ncols is the number of columns in the figure.

Here's a working example that uses the Pandas DataFrame boxplot method:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[6,8,2],'c':[9,1,7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[15,23,32],'b':[6,80,2],'c':[9,10,7]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.2,0.5,0.5],'b':[18,5,2],'c':[9,7,7]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[51,32,20],'b':[4,3,20],'c':[7,2,1]})

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 =fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
df1.boxplot(ax = ax1)
ax2 =fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
df2.boxplot(ax = ax2)
ax3 =fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
df3.boxplot(ax = ax3)
ax4 =fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)
df4.boxplot(ax = ax4)
plt.show()
```

[image]
I'm not sure why your plots are all empty. I'd check the contents of the DataFrames you are plotting.

Comment: Ah, very nice. Thank you so much.

Comment: So, it solved most of my problems, but then more arose. Now, I have 5 figures. One has data in it and is a large figure where it looks like all of my four separate graphs have been dumped, while the other four are each the subplots that I wish my data to be on, all in four different windows with no data. I edited my original post to update the code.

Comment: Try explicitly adding the subplots to the figure and and passing the axes to the boxplot call. I modified my example to show what I mean.